# is it a good idea to use before for multiple tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I have a class, which has multiple methods. I am looking at the test cases written by someone.

The tests look like this..

```js
describe('this tests example class', () => {
   let classInstance;
   before(() => {
     classInstance = new ExampleClass();
   })

   describe("tests 1", () => {
      it("first test", () => {
    
      })

      it("second test", () => {
    
      })

   })

   describe("tests 2", () => {
      it("third test", () => {
    
      })

      it("fourth test", () => {
    
      })

   })

}
```

let's say `ExampleClass` has a function `func1` which has a parameter number and it pushes this number in the global array of its own.

Now `first test` calls `func1` and it passes 5 as a number. Now, `first test` does something else too, but nothing important. We can look at the `second test` now, which checks if the `ExampleClass`'s array has the number 5.

So, the way this works now is `first test` puts something on the global `classInstance` and `second test` checks if it's there..

**The question:** Does these kind of tests ever make sense at all ? I think good approach would be to have `beforeEach` and each test would work on the new instance of `classInstance`, but i think that this would cause more code for the test cases. Would appreciate your comment on this.

Comment: It really depends, think about if you want to re-instantiate the class before each test, if so, use `beforeEach`. If you don't really need that (calling method from that class does not affect your following tests logic), don't do that.

Comment: the idea is that if you remove `first test` from my example, `second test` will fail. Is this ever a good approach at all ?

Comment: Mm so that means that tests are dependent to some method executions, instantiating the class using `beforeAll` LGTM!

Comment: so what you're saying is it's fine that removing `first test` makes `second test` fail ?